# Multi Dimension Python Lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am new to python 3 and trying to work with a list but struggling. I have read things but some are quite confusing, so I have been playing with code but getting nowhere fast.

I want to store 3 elements (Count,Angle,Speed) for every second of the day which is 86400 entries.

To make things easier for this example lets have a list of 2 entries of 3 elements
I created a list and initially want to set every element to 0

```
a = [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]
print(a[0])
print(a[0][0])
print(a[0][1])
print(a[0][2])
print(a[1])
print(a[1][0])
print(a[1][1])
print(a[1][2])
print("** Change a[0][2] to 7 from 0")
a[0][2] = 7
print(a[0])
print(a[0][0])
print(a[0][1])
print(a[0][2])
print("-----------")
print(a[1])
print(a[1][0])
print(a[1][1])
print(a[1][2])
print("-----------")
```

This works great and for example I am able to access and change a[0][2]

### [0, 0, 0]
0
0
0
[0, 0, 0]
0
0
0
** Change a[0][2] to 7 from 0
[0, 0, 7]
0
0
7

### [0, 0, 0]
0
0
0

However I want to be able to pre-fill the list with 0 as it will be tedious to do it for 86400 entries but again for this example lets go with 2

So I read up and seen how to do it using... a = [[0,0,0]] * 2

```
a = [[0,0,0]] * 2
print(a[0])
print(a[0][0])
print(a[0][1])
print(a[0][2])
print(a[1])
print(a[1][0])
print(a[1][1])
print(a[1][2])
print("** Change a[0][2] to 7 from 0")
a[0][2] = 7
print(a[0])
print(a[0][0])
print(a[0][1])
print(a[0][2])
print("-----------")
print(a[1])
print(a[1][0])
print(a[1][1])
print(a[1][2])
print("-----------")
```

However why does a[1][2] also change to 7

### [0, 0, 0]
0
0
0
[0, 0, 0]
0
0
0
** Change a[0][2] to 7 from 0
[0, 0, 7]
0
0
7

### [0, 0, 7]
0
0
7

I have obviously done something wrong with pre-filling the list or even defining the list, so if anybody can help I would be grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
[[0,0,0]]*2
```

means that you evaluate `[0,0,0]`, that is build such a list. And then create an array of 2 elements whose each element is this `[0,0,0]`. So it is the same one!

It is like doing

```py
arr=[]
arr0=[0,0,0]
for i in range(2):
    arr.append(arr0)
```

So, since `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` are the same list, altering one, alters the other.

Note that changing `arr[0]` does not alter `arr[1]`. Because that is changing the content of `arr` not of `arr[0]`.

So

```py
arr=[[0,0,0]]*2
arr[0]=12
# arr = [12, [0,0,0]], not [12,12]
```

What you need to do is to build a new `[0,0,0]` for each line.

For example like this

```py
arr=[ [0]*3 for _ in range(2) ]
arr[0][2]=7
# [[0, 0, 7], [0, 0, 0]]
```

Or, alternative, using numpy

```py
import numpy as np
arr=np.zeros((86400, 3))
arr[0,2]=7
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use numpy to create array of dimension 86400, 3

```
import numpy as np
a=np.zeros((86400, 3))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to use the numpy module for big numerical arrays as access is very efficient - worth reading up on. You can easily create a numpy array of any shape and fill with zeros (ints or floats)

```
import numpy as np

x = np.zeros((86400, 3), dtype = int)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a list of list `86400 x 3` like this.

```
l = [[0]*3 for _ in range(86400)]
```